# USB 3.0 port with USB 3.0 device in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, usb

When I try to connect a USB 3.0 device in Ubuntu 12.10 (ASUS K55VD, kernel 3.5.0-19-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP), the system says

```
[   74.747832] hub 3-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 1
[   74.931957] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[   74.949390] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0731
[   74.949396] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=2
[   74.949400] usb 4-1: Product: USB Storage
[   74.949403] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 0000000000000033
[   75.033327] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[   75.038548] Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
[   75.038651] scsi7 : usb-storage 4-1:1.0
[   75.038700] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[   75.038701] USB Mass Storage support registered.
```

but it does not recognize the device, and the disks applications (gparted, nautilus) act as if nothing had been connected.
I have checked other questions, but either they have no answers or they told about previous Ubuntu version with 3.0.x kernels.

A USB 2.0 device will work in the USB 3.0 ports.
A USB 3.0 device will work (at USB 2.0 speeds) in the USB 2.0 ports.
The problem, as I wrote, is between USB 3.0 devices and USB 3.0 ports.

I have my USB 3.0 ports configured without legacy support via the BIOS (the way they should be, I suppose). But I also have tried to configure them with XHCI Preboot mode disabled.

Have any one solved a similar problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: ubuntu supports usb3 since 9.10 kernel 2.6 and you can connect usb3 . does your usb work in another pc ?

Comment: @EnesKuray, the USB 3.0 device works in windows 7 and windows 8.
I have edited my question. Here is more information:

"A USB 2.0 device will work in the USB 3.0 ports. A USB 3.0 device will work (at USB 2.0 speeds) in the USB 2.0 ports. The problem, as I wrote, is between USB 3.0 devices and USB 3.0 ports."

Comment: can you update kernel to 3.6.6?

Comment: Which feature has 3.6.6 that beats 3.5.x?
Is there any repository available?
Or do I need to compile it?

Comment: usb support is about kernel . http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/11/install-linux-kernel-366-in-ubuntu.html

Comment: Sorry no answer but I have the Exact same problem!! All hardware is working just fine. My USB 3.0 work just fine AS LONG as I do not connect a USB 3.0 device to it!. I dual boot and under windows 7 everything works just fine, so the drive and the port work just fine. It is not just the version of device either, I have a few different USB 3.0 devices that all work just fine in Win7 just not Ubuntu. I currently and running the new Kern 3.6.6 as well. My Laptop hardware works just fine as long as the devices are USB 2.0 and not USB 3.0. Any advice? Sisco

Comment: To close voters, this question has been perfectly on topic at the time it was asked, so I'm voting to leave open. See also https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16132/please-dont-flag-old-questions-as-eol

Answer (score 1):

If the following does not work then I suggest you read [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug/137915#137915)

Some users have reported the same issues on Windows 7 & Windows 8. The solution was doing the first 2 steps provided in [here](http://support.asus.com/Troubleshooting/detail.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=K55VD&p=3&s=386&os=&hashedid=kE5VnnR4vrXQdDVT&no=444) which were basically:

1. Update the BIOS
2. Make sure that in the BIOS (After upgrading it) you check that in `Advanced -> Chipset -> Southbridge` the option **USB 1.1 OHCI Controllers** and **USB 2.0 EHCI Controllers** are "enabled". Of course, there are a couple of K55VD Models, so this applies to some of them.

The general idea is to do the steps for the BIOS. If it works great. If not, you have just found a bug my friend. So file the bug using the link above and a developer will help.